# How to use Uno Platform with Windows Community Toolkit

Tags: c#, android, uno-platform, windows-community-toolkit

I tried to make a demo application with [this](https://platform.uno/docs/articles/get-started-dotnet-new.html#uno-platform-blank-prism-application) Uno Platform template.
All I wanted to do is add winui2 with [this example](https://platform.uno/docs/articles/features/using-winui2.html) and add the Windows Community Toolkit with [this example](https://platform.uno/docs/articles/uno-community-toolkit.html?tabs=tabid-vswin).

When doing the things mentioned in the tutorial for the Windows Community Toolkit, which is to install the following Nuget package:

- **Uno**.Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls.DataGrid

  - For iOS, Android, Web (WebAssembly)
    [image: For Android:]
- Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls.DataGrid

  - For the UWP app

and use the following reference in my XAML:
`xmlns:controls="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls"`

In the XAML-file I added the following code-snipped provided by the tutorial:

```xml
<controls:DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid">
    <controls:DataGrid.Columns>
        <controls:DataGridTextColumn Header="Rank"/>
        <controls:DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Mountain"/>
    </controls:DataGrid.Columns>
</controls:DataGrid>
```

Leading me to the following XAML-file in my Shell.xaml:

```xml
<ContentControl
    x:Class="AndroidTest.Views.Shell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:AndroidTest"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:prismMvvm="using:Prism.Mvvm"
    xmlns:prismRegions="using:Prism.Regions"

    xmlns:winui="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls"
    xmlns:controls="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls"

    prismMvvm:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True"
    mc:Ignorable="d">


    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Margin="20">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" FontSize="30" />
            <TextBlock Text="Welcome to Uno/WinUI and Prism!" FontSize="15" />

            <!-- winui -->
            <winui:NumberBox />
            <!-- community toolkit -->
            <controls:DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid">
                <controls:DataGrid.Columns>
                    <controls:DataGridTextColumn Header="Rank"/>
                    <controls:DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Mountain"/>
                </controls:DataGrid.Columns>
            </controls:DataGrid>

        </StackPanel>
        <ContentControl Grid.Row="1" prismRegions:RegionManager.RegionName="ContentRegion" />
    </Grid>
</ContentControl>
```

Now the code works fine for UWP, but it does not work with Android anymore. I get this error message in `App.xaml.cs`:

```
Prism.Ioc.ContainerResolutionException: 'An unexpected error occurred while resolving 'AndroidTest.Views.Shell''
```

At the function:

```
protected override UIElement CreateShell()
{
    return Container.Resolve<Shell>();
}
```

And the following output:

```
Loaded assembly: /data/user/0/AndroidTest.AndroidTest/files/.__override__/System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll [External]
[0:] The Bindable attribute is missing and the type [Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.TextBlock] is not known by the MetadataProvider. Reflection was used instead of the binding engine and generated static metadata. Add the Bindable attribute to prevent this message and performance issues.
[0:] The Bindable attribute is missing and the type [Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.TextBox] is not known by the MetadataProvider. Reflection was used instead of the binding engine and generated static metadata. Add the Bindable attribute to prevent this message and performance issues.
[0:] The Bindable attribute is missing and the type [Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Control] is not known by the MetadataProvider. Reflection was used instead of the binding engine and generated static metadata. Add the Bindable attribute to prevent this message and performance issues.
[0:] The Bindable attribute is missing and the type [Windows.UI.Xaml.FrameworkElement] is not known by the MetadataProvider. Reflection was used instead of the binding engine and generated static metadata. Add the Bindable attribute to prevent this message and performance issues.
[0:] The Bindable attribute is missing and the type [Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Border] is not known by the MetadataProvider. Reflection was used instead of the binding engine and generated static metadata. Add the Bindable attribute to prevent this message and performance issues.
[0:] The Bindable attribute is missing and the type [Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ScrollViewer] is not known by the MetadataProvider. Reflection was used instead of the binding engine and generated static metadata. Add the Bindable attribute to prevent this message and performance issues.
[est.AndroidTes] Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->initializeScrollbars(Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;)V (greylist, JNI, allowed)
[0:] The Bindable attribute is missing and the type [Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Grid] is not known by the MetadataProvider. Reflection was used instead of the binding engine and generated static metadata. Add the Bindable attribute to prevent this message and performance issues.
[0:] The Bindable attribute is missing and the type [Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Button] is not known by the MetadataProvider. Reflection was used instead of the binding engine and generated static metadata. Add the Bindable attribute to prevent this message and performance issues.
[est.AndroidTes] Explicit concurrent copying GC freed 90(37KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 24% free, 2487KB/3316KB, paused 289us total 3.144ms
[0:] The Bindable attribute is missing and the type [Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ContentPresenter] is not known by the MetadataProvider. Reflection was used instead of the binding engine and generated static metadata. Add the Bindable attribute to prevent this message and performance issues.
[0:] The Bindable attribute is missing and the type [Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives.RepeatButton] is not known by the MetadataProvider. Reflection was used instead of the binding engine and generated static metadata. Add the Bindable attribute to prevent this message and performance issues.
[0:] The Bindable attribute is missing and the type [Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.NumberBox] is not known by the MetadataProvider. Reflection was used instead of the binding engine and generated static metadata. Add the Bindable attribute to prevent this message and performance issues.
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly en-US/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls.DataGrid.resources.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly en/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls.DataGrid.resources.dll
**Prism.Ioc.ContainerResolutionException:** 'An unexpected error occurred while resolving 'AndroidTest.Views.Shell''
```

Any ideas of what I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a problem with different versions of NuGet packages and problems with their dependencies.
For a functioning app with Uno Platform, Prism Library and the Windows Community Toolkit you need the following versions:

- Uno Template [Version 3.7.4](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Uno.ProjectTemplates.Dotnet/3.7.4)
- Uno.Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls.DataGrid [Version 7.0.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Uno.Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls.DataGrid/7.0.0?_src=template).

When installing these NuGet packages versions all dependencies are correct and it works fine.

Comment: How's the performance for you? Mine is almost horribly slow

Comment: I haven't tried this for over a year so I cannot really remember. I remember running it in an emulator with not that good of a performance but when running it on an actual Tablet it was working quite fine. (I cannot try/reproduce this so this is just a memory write up)

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is likely to be a linker issue. You can take a look at the [documentation from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/linker).

Comment: Thanks for your help! I've found the solution for my problem by looking through all dependencies of my NuGet packages and found out that I was using incompatible versions. After adjusting the versions of all NuGet packages it works fine.